# Choosing a chat-bot framework for data science research project and understanding the hidden costs of the development and rollout?

Tags: data-science, chatbot, rasa, conversational-ai

The question is about using a chat-bot framework in a research study, where one would like to measure the improvement of a rule-based decision process over time.
For example, we would like to understand how to improve the process of medical condition identification (and treatment) using the minimal set of guided questions and patient interaction.

Medical condition can be formulated into a work-flow rules by doctors; possible technical approach for such study would be developing an app or web site that can be accessed by patients, where they can ask free text questions that a predefined rule-based chat-bot will address. During the study there will be a doctor monitoring the collected data and improving the rules and the possible responses (and also provide new responses when the workflow has reached a dead-end), we do plan to collect the conversations and apply machine learning to generate improved work-flow tree (and questions) over time, however the plan is to do any data analysis and processing offline, there is no intention of building a full product.
This is a low budget academy study, and the PHD student has good development skills and data science knowledge (python) and will be accompanied by a fellow student that will work on the engineering side. One of the conversational-AI options recommended for data scientists was RASA.

I invested the last few days reading and playing with several chat-bots solutions: RASA, Botpress, also looked at Dialogflow and read tons of comparison material which makes it more challenging.

From the sources on the internet it seems that RASA might be a better fit for data science projects, however it would be great to get a sense of the real learning curve and how fast one can expect to have a working bot, and the especially one that has to continuously update the rules.

Few things to clarify, We do have data to generate the questions and in touch with doctors to improve the quality, it seems that we need a way to introduce participants with multiple choices and provide answers (not just free text), being in the research side there is also no need to align with any specific big provider (i.e. Google, Amazon or Microsoft) unless it has a benefit, the important consideration are time, money and felxability, we would like to have a working approach in few weeks (and continuously improve it) the whole experiment will run for no more than 3-4 months. We do need to be able to extract all the data. We are not sure about which channel is best for such study WhatsApp? Website? Other? and what are the involved complexities?

Any thoughts about the challenges and considerations about dealing with chat-bots would be valuable.

Comment: hello I already did a job similar to your request! you can see the source code on my GitHub https://github.com/adrien1020/ChatBotAPI. If you’re satisfied with this job I’ll let you buy me a coffee at https://www.buymeacoffee.com/adr1021

Comment: I am working with Rasa with a very similar purpose. If the answer is still useful to you (it has been 25 days) let me know to write as much as I have found so far.